# How to remove DOM nodes in Firefox consecutively?

Tags: javascript, firefox, removechild

I am trying to remove a division element (a modal window) from the DOM in Firefox.

The first time I remove the Modal Window; everything works fine.  When I open the window a second time and try to remove it; it does not work.

Specifically, I get an error message saying that the parent element of the Modal Window cannot be found.

The parent element is document.body and I tried using parentNode.removeChild() and parentNode.replaceChild().  I, however, have no issues in Chrome or Internet Explorer 8.

What is the proper/bulletproof way of removing nodes from the DOM?

The HTML:

```
<body>

<!--The modal window:!-->

<div id="modalwin"></div>


<!--An overlay division stacked behind the
 modal window using CSS z-index: !-->

<div id="uiOverlay"></div>


<!--The listener:!-->

<a href="#" onClick='Delete(modalwin); Delete(uiOverlay); return false;' />

</body>
```

---

The Javascript

```
Delete: function (elem) {

        if (!elem) {

            return false;
        }
        var blank = document.createTextNode(' ');

        try {

            var ref = elem.parentNode.replaceChild(blank, elem); 

        } catch (err) {

           elem.style.display = "none";
        }

      //  return true;
    },
```

---

The Firebug error

NotFound Error: Node was not found
(the node which is not found is the document.body / the parent of the modal window division)

Comment: Is the modal dialog getting removed from the DOM and thus has no parent?

Comment: The modal window is created with Javascript ( i forgot to mention that) so I am assuming once another window is created it is a new node with a parent?

Comment: Per your report, the one you're operating on doesn't have a parent, therefore it must be removed from the DOM already because everything in the DOM has a parent.  You haven't disclosed enough info for us to have any idea why that is, but that is the direction you will need to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Once an element is removed, it still exists but has no parent node. It can be attached elsewhere, or just discarded and left to the garbage collector to clean up.

So once you call `Delete` on the element once, calling it again will try to remove an already removed node, which fails.